# Unable to Deserialize multiple list in XML with RestSharp

Tags: c#, xml, list, deserialization, restsharp

I'm get this XML as a response to a rest call.  The original list comes back populated fine but the list within the CollectorDate class returns null for all properties.  How do I get this to Deserialize properly?

```
<CollectorHeardMIUs>
    <CollectorDate Date="2018/07/16" CollectorId="11090_5000">
        <CollectorLatitude></CollectorLatitude>
        <CollectorLongitude></CollectorLongitude>
        <Miu MiuId="1461860710">
            <PremiseID>859869749</PremiseID>
            <PremiseAccount>Unknown</PremiseAccount>
            <PremiseLatitude>39.31553</PremiseLatitude>
            <PremiseLongitude>-84.608627</PremiseLongitude>
        </Miu>
        <Miu MiuId="1478541235">
            <PremiseID>859251478</PremiseID>
            <PremiseAccount>Unknown</PremiseAccount>
            <PremiseLatitude>39.36231</PremiseLatitude>
            <PremiseLongitude>-84.54222</PremiseLongitude>
        </Miu>
    </CollectorDate>
    <CollectorDate Date="2018/07/17" CollectorId="11090_5000">
        <CollectorLatitude></CollectorLatitude>
        <CollectorLongitude></CollectorLongitude>
        <Miu MiuId="1461860710">
            <PremiseID>859869749</PremiseID>
            <PremiseAccount>Unknown</PremiseAccount>
            <PremiseLatitude>39.31553</PremiseLatitude>
            <PremiseLongitude>-84.608627</PremiseLongitude>
        </Miu>
    </CollectorDate>
</CollectorHeardMIUs>
<CollectorHeardMIUs>
    <CollectorDate Date="2018/07/16" CollectorId="11090_5000">
        <CollectorLatitude></CollectorLatitude>
        <CollectorLongitude></CollectorLongitude>
        <Miu MiuId="1461860710">
            <PremiseID>859869749</PremiseID>
            <PremiseAccount>Unknown</PremiseAccount>
            <PremiseLatitude>39.31553</PremiseLatitude>
            <PremiseLongitude>-84.608627</PremiseLongitude>
        </Miu>
    </CollectorDate>
    <CollectorDate Date="2018/07/17" CollectorId="11090_5000">
        <CollectorLatitude></CollectorLatitude>
        <CollectorLongitude></CollectorLongitude>
        <Miu MiuId="1461860710">
            <PremiseID>859869749</PremiseID>
            <PremiseAccount>Unknown</PremiseAccount>
            <PremiseLatitude>39.31553</PremiseLatitude>
            <PremiseLongitude>-84.608627</PremiseLongitude>
        </Miu>
    </CollectorDate>
</CollectorHeardMIUs>
```

Here are my classes:

```
     public class CollectorDate
        {
            public string Date { get; set; }
            public string CollectorId{ get; set; }
            public decimal? CollectorLatitude { get; set; }
            public decimal? CollectorLongitude { get; set; }
            public List<Miu> Miu { get; set; }
        }
        public class Miu
        {
            public string MiuId { get; set; }
            public string PremiseID { get; set; }
            public string PremiseAccount { get; set; }
            public decimal? PremiseLatitude { get; set; }
            public decimal? PremiseLongitude { get; set; }

        }
```

And my RestSharp method:

```
static List<CollectorDate> GetCollectorHeardMius(string token, DateTime startdt, DateTime enddt, string collectorId)
{
    var client = new RestClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ApiURL"));
    var request = new RestRequest("collector_heard_mius");
    request.AddParameter("token", token);
    request.AddParameter("site_id", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SiteId"));
    request.AddParameter("start_date", startdt.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"));
    request.AddParameter("end_date", enddt.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"));
    request.AddParameter("collector_id", collectorId);
    var response = client.Execute<List<CollectorDate>>(request);
    return response.Data;
}
```

I have tried adding a class for the root element of CollectorHeardMIUs which only contains a single property of List CollectorDate but that returns a   List with all empty properties.

I think the issue is with there not being a named tag for the lists of CollectorDate and Miu that is separate but I can't figure out how to handle it.

Comment: XML can have only one root element.

Comment: I need to see the parent class of CollectorDate.  It is an array  put you should not pyt [XmlArray] which requires two levels of Xml tags.  Instead use [XmlElement].

Comment: check my answer and let me know @realityisrelative

Comment: The root node is CollectorHeardMIUs.  That is not a list despite the plural naming.  I tried adding the XMLRoot.  I added a class for that simply containing one property 
public List<CollectorDate> CollectorDate { get; set; }  and the repsonse to var response = client.Execute<CollectorHeardMIUs>(request);  but that still doesn;t work.

Comment: Refer my logic first after getting response append root before and after string and then deserialize @realityisrelative

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to get root Element use this code:

So I have Created a Test Application And this is Tested

So just Append it and then Deserialize it and check my model also

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //I am simply loading data From this file you can simply replace with data which are getting from rest Api 
            string data = File.ReadAllText("D:\\xml.txt");
            string appender = "<root>" + data + "</root>";
            XmlSerializer xmldata = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

            object datafromXml = xmldata.Deserialize(stream);

        }
    }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Miu")]
        public class Miu
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "PremiseID")]
            public string PremiseID { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "PremiseAccount")]
            public string PremiseAccount { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "PremiseLatitude")]
            public string PremiseLatitude { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "PremiseLongitude")]
            public string PremiseLongitude { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "MiuId")]
            public string MiuId { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "CollectorDate")]
        public class CollectorDate
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "CollectorLatitude")]
            public string CollectorLatitude { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "CollectorLongitude")]
            public string CollectorLongitude { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Miu")]
            public List<Miu> Miu { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Date")]
            public string Date { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "CollectorId")]
            public string CollectorId { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "CollectorHeardMIUs")]
        public class CollectorHeardMIUs
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "CollectorDate")]
            public List<CollectorDate> CollectorDate { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "root")]
        public class Root
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "CollectorHeardMIUs")]
            public List<CollectorHeardMIUs> CollectorHeardMIUs { get; set; }
        }

    }
```

Comment: I'm getting the data from a Restful service and using RestSharp packages to get it.  This implementation doesn't seem to work with its deserializer.

Comment: but @realityisrelative RestSharp will give you data use that in your case i have mention in comment also

Comment: for example var content = response.Content; // raw content as string
you will get raw string replace my data variable with this